# Azure Event Grid not sending events to webhook

Tags: azure, azure-media-services, azure-eventgrid

I have an Azure media services account for which I want to be notified via webhook when encoding jobs are finished. I'm using v3 of the Media Service API.

I've added an event subscription to this account and have sucessfully validated the webhook endpoint.

Here's where the problem comes in. If I do something that should trigger an event(start an encoding job, create an asset, etc.) on the Azure Portal nothing happens event wise. Looking at the event subscription on the Portal shows no events detected as well.

Is this an Azure bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, actions done through the Portal or v2 of the API does not trigger Events from Event Grid.

I used [Azure Media Services Explorer](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Media-Services-Explorer) to test out my webhooks instead.